# Repeating parameter value inside $.each

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$.each(main_array, function (index, value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '..php_location_from_outer_space',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see. The above code is calling a post method inside array each (if I`m not mistaken it is a loop).

Now here is my php

```
$date = date('mdYHis', time());
$id = "UID" . $_SESSION["id"] . "BID" . $_SESSION["branch_id"] . $date;
echo $id;
```

Im assuming that my output will be like this

```
UID1BID03062020114201
UID1BID03062020114202
UID1BID03062020114203
UID1BID03062020114204
UID1BID03062020114205
UID1BID03062020114206
UID1BID03062020114207
```

and so on based on loop from the js. However this is what I get

```
UID1BID03062020114201
UID1BID03062020114201
UID1BID03062020114201
UID1BID03062020114201
UID1BID03062020114201
UID1BID03062020114201
```

how can i fix this issue to refresh the parameter inside the loop

Thanks

Comment: The last digit is the seconds component from a date. If you send them all in the same second, this what you will get.

Comment: Thats true it is the second from a date however i didnt pass it in a same second because it is came from a loop so probably a second has passed while the loop is moving am i right?

Comment: It is entirely possible that a loop will execute in much less than 1 second.

Comment: really!? i didnt expect that... what would be the best approach for this? a delay??

Answer (score 0):

I didnt expect that a loop with seconds can be run in second based on what **ryantxr** said so I dont know if its this the right way but heres how i do it

```
var count = 0;
$.each(main_array, function (index, value) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        /* Whatever code you want to explore the universe  */
    }, count * 1000)
    count++;
});
```